# how to use map in react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

Currently using a react in typescript.
make a separate file and manage it.
I want to do map work on the `card component

parameter on the map wrong?
definition wrong?
Can I get some advice...

`Card.tsx`

```
import { LIST_DATA, ListData } from './data';

const Card = () => {
return(
  {LIST_DATA.map(({ id, title }: ListData[]) => {
    return <S.InfoTitle key={id}>{title}</S.InfoTitle>;
  })}
)
}
```

`data.tsx`

```
export interface ListData {
  id: number;
  title: string;
}

export const LIST_DATA: ListData[] = [
  {
    id: 0,
    title: 'drawing',
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'total',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'method',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'material',
  },
];
```

Comment: since map function parameter is a single item remove array brackets from type


{LIST_DATA.map(({ id, title }: ListData) => {
    return <S.InfoTitle key={id}>{title}</S.InfoTitle>;
  })}

Answer (score -1):

When you map, each item inside the map as argument is only one item from the original array. In your case you have an array of ListData but when you map each argument is only one of this ListData item type, therefore you have to change ListData[] to ListData as such:

```
import { LIST_DATA, ListData } from './data';

const Card = () => {
   return(
     {LIST_DATA.map(({ id, title }: ListData) => {
       return <S.InfoTitle key={id}>{title}</S.InfoTitle>;
     })}
   )
}
```

Otherwise to answer the main question: map in typescript is the same as map in javascript, you just have to ensure you input the right type in order to "secure" your app.